# Does S3 Replication/S3 Batch Ops offer Data Integrity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case where we want to transfer data between AWS Accounts. I want to use the S3 Replication/S3 Batch Ops/DataSync provided they can ensure the data integrity so that I don't have to use additional checks after data is transferred.

Answer (score -1):

I have used S3 document sync across two different AWS accounts via AWS CLI. My use case was to push data from one bucket to another bucket in different AWS accounts so I used AWS CLI command.

I was satisfied with the Data Integrity in this process. Next time when I used to run the sync, it used to transfer only newly created item in source S3 bucket.